# Updating a JLabel with a Static Integer

Tags: java

So I'm new to Java, I took a class in highschool last year and want to try and make my own little 2d game that Im working on. I have a stats.java that is filled with all the variables I want stored, such as cash, name, level, etc. Right now Im trying to add Cash to my Cash JLabel using a button.

```
JButton btnAddCash = new JButton("ADD 10,000");
btnAddCash.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        stats.cash = (stats.cash + 5000);
    }
});

JLabel lblCash = new JLabel("Cash: " +stats.cash);
lblCash.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
lblCash.setBounds(10, 649, 162, 14);
contentPane.add(lblCash);
lblCash.setFont(new Font("AirbusMCDUa", Font.BOLD, 15));
JButton debugBtn = new JButton("");
```

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: 1. Don't use static fields without a good reason, and I can guarantee that the reason you're using it at this time, is not a good one. 2. You've posted requirements and a small code snippet that doesn't look to be enough to give us an idea what your problem might be. Instead you should tell the details of the problem and post a valid [mcve] to help us better understand both your code and your problem. Good luck.

Comment: Your actionPerformed method just updates the field but does not set the JLabel's text -- you need to explicitly do this as the JLabel will not magically update itself. It is not tied to the stats.cash field but rather only holds its value at the time of creation -- that's your main problem.

Comment: Thankyou so much I removed the Static and made it so it set the text every click, it seems to be working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here at (A) and (B)

```
JButton btnAddCash = new JButton("ADD 10,000");
btnAddCash.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        stats.cash = (stats.cash + 5000); //     (A)
    }
});

JLabel lblCash = new JLabel("Cash: " +stats.cash); //     (B)
```

Understand that when  you create the JLabel it holds the **present value of the cash field** and does not hold a reference to the field itself. This is important since updating the cash field will have no effect on the JLabel's text. You must explicitly change that text:

```
btnAddCash.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        stats.cash = (stats.cash + 5000);    
        lblCash.setText("Cash: " +stats.cash);  // ****** update the text
    }
});
```

Other issues:

- Again, avoid static unless you have a good reason for using this
- Look up the Model-View-Controller design pattern and study it. This type of structure is what you will eventually want to use.
- Avoid absolute positioning of components (null layouts and `setBounds`) as this will lead to frustration, grief and poor GUI's. Use layout managers
- Consider learning JavaFX instead of Swing since JavaFX is being supported actively by Oracle while Swing is not.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to update your JLabel !

```
JLabel lblCash = new JLabel("Cash: " + stats.cash);

lblCash.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
lblCash.setBounds(10, 649, 162, 14);
lblCash.setFont(new Font("AirbusMCDUa", Font.BOLD, 15));
contentPane.add(lblCash);

JButton btnAddCash = new JButton("ADD 10,000");
btnAddCash.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        stats.cash += 5000;                        // += is faster
        lblCash.setText("Cash: " + stats.cash);    // <-- Here
    }
});
contentPane.add(btnAddCash);                       // <-- Here

JButton debugBtn = new JButton("");
```